# Assertion text response failed

Tags: jmeter, assertion, responsetext

I got response data from the URL path....But am getting assertion test result failed...
please refer below screen shots and help me out from this.[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Can you provide response as well?

Comment: Are you sure your html response contains : > Cx360 - Home

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/RHU2BBdc3O

Comment: please go with the above response data link.......This is what am getting while doing assertion testing.......otherwise output gets green

Comment: You need to put Response asserion on a sampler with the response you are asserting...

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/RHU2BBdc3O

Comment: yes this what is am getting....see the screen shot link you will get the data as well.....

Comment: in your screenshot you have 2 reponses can you show each as long as the link name (enlarge left panel)

Comment: Could not understand!!!...could you pls explain bit more?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I was looking at a wrong picture.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/VmIUensy2fT....

Comment: above is a clear picture for you

Comment: Ok fine...was that correct am placed the assertion text there? or else give a idea to get it done pls

Comment: I want you to click on each link and show the request tab and response tabs on the right

Comment: Request-----http://screencast.com/t/ZeHlT1eQ

Comment: Response-----http://screencast.com/t/dM9PNdQvngZ

Comment: please show also sampler result tab AND show the 3 tabs for the second url

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your Response Assertion **as a child of the "Member Page" request**, elsewise it will be applied to the wrong sampler or all samplers living at the same level.
2. Change your Response Assertion scope (Apply to) to `Main sample and sub-samples` (it seems that result comes not form main sample, but from a redirected page)
3. Change Pattern Matching Rules to "Substring". Particularly in above case for `Cx360 - Home` text it should be fine, but remember that "Contains" and "Matches" modes treat the expected value as [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html)

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for comprehensive information on conditionally passing and failing JMeter samplers using assertions.

Comment: Did you take your eyes close to Members page response(There is 2 responses under Member page)......May I know why it was?